# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que se repita el menú hasta que el usuario elija la opción salir?

Tags: c++, c

Buenas tengo el siguiente codigo y quisiera que este se repitiera hasta que el usuario ingrese el valor que dice la opcion alguna manera? de como poder que no salga del codigo hasta que se termine de trabajar con este claro todas las opciones depende de la primera para seguir trabajando con normalidad pero no quiero que se cierre el programa hasta que el usuario lo pida en realidad me gustaria que me ayudaran en esto en realidad

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void Leercargarunarchivo();
void Visualizarmatrizsinordenar();
void Visualizarmatrizordenada();
void ListadePalabraPalindromo();
void Listadeverbos();
void menu();

main();
int opc;
      cout << "\n\n\tMenu de Opciones";
        cout << "\n\--------------------------------------";
        cout << "\n\t1. Leer y cargar un archivo";
        cout << "\n\t2. Visualizar matriz sin ordenar";
        cout << "\n\t3. Visualizar matriz ordenada";
        cout << "\n\t4. Lista de Palabra Palindromo" ;
        cout << "\n\t5. Lista de verbos";
        cout << "\n\t6. SALIR";
        cout << "\n\--------------------------------------";
        cout << "\n eliga una opcion:";
        cin>>opc;

     if (opc==1)
        void Leercargarunarchivo();
       if (opc==2)
        void Visualizarmatrizsinordenar();
       if (opc==3)
        void Visualizarmatrizordenada();
       if (opc==4)
        void ListadePalabraPalindromo();
       if (opc==5)
        void Listadeverbos();
       else if (opc==6)
        cout<<"\n Gracias por usar el programa :)";

void leerarchivo(){
    string nombreArchivo,texto;
    ifstream archivo;
    cout <<"hola que tal";   
    
    cout<<"Digite el nombre o la ubicacion del archivo o fichero: ";
    getline(cin,nombreArchivo);
    
    archivo.open(nombreArchivo.c_str(),ios::in); //Abrimos el archivo en modo lectura
    
    if(archivo.fail()){
        cout<<"No se pudo abrir el archivo";
        exit(1);
    }
    
    while(!archivo.eof()){ //mientras no sea final del archivo
        getline(archivo,texto);
        cout<<texto<<endl;
    }
    
    archivo.close(); //Cerramos el archivo
} 
    
void matrizdepalabras(){
    

}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! esto no parece tener nada que ver con c#... y lo unico que tenes que hacer es envolver todo en un while para que no salga hasta que seleccione la opcion de salida...

Comment: Lo estás corriendo en C++ o C?

Comment: Reforzando la respuesta de @PaperBirdMaster, quita el retorno `void` de las funciones cuando éstas son llamadas.

Answer (score 1):

Eso que muestras ni siquiera compila: `main` no tiene cuerpo, ni tipo de retorno ni está definida.

Si quieres que algo se repita, usa un bucle:

```
enum opciones
{
    Leer_y_cargar = 1,
    Visualizar_sin_ordenar = 2,
    Visualizar_ordenada = 3,
    Lista_Palindromo = 4,
    Lista_verbos = 5,
    SALIR = 6,
};

opciones opcion;

do
{
    cout << "\n\n\tMenu de Opciones";
            "\n\--------------------------------------"
            "\n\t1. Leer y cargar un archivo"
            "\n\t2. Visualizar matriz sin ordenar"
            "\n\t3. Visualizar matriz ordenada"
            "\n\t4. Lista de Palabra Palindromo"
            "\n\t5. Lista de verbos"
            "\n\t6. SALIR";
            "\n\--------------------------------------"
            "\n eliga una opcion:";

    cin >> opcion;

    switch (opcion)
    {
        case Leer_y_cargar:
            // blah blah
            break;
        case Visualizar_sin_ordenar:
            // blah blah
            break;
        case Visualizar_ordenada:
            // blah blah
            break;
        case Lista_Palindromo:
            // blah blah
            break;
        case Lista_verbos:
            // blah blah
            break;
    }
} while (opcion == SALIR);
```

A parte de que tu código no compila, las cabeceras `<conio.h>`, `<stdio.h>`, `<string.h>`, `<fstream>` y `<stdlib.h>` son de C y no deben usarse en C++.